# Always getting upright numbers in references created with \cref, with italic-correction for conjunction between references

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, italic-correction

How do I make it so that I get upright numbers all the time in references created with `\cref`? I believe I'm supposed to do this with `\crefdefaultlabelformat{#2\textup{#1}#3}`. But in my example below, I don't seem to be getting the italic correction before the "2" in the sentence created by `\emph{A reference to \cref{thm1,thm2}.}` (compare with the sentence created by `\emph{A reference to Theorems \textup{1} and \textup{2}.}` just below it).

My example uses some other packages that I'll need to be using.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage[capitalise,nameinlink]{cleveref}

\crefdefaultlabelformat{#2\textup{#1}#3}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}\label{thm1}
A theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}\label{thm2}
A theorem.
\end{theorem}

\emph{A reference to \cref{thm1,thm2}.}

\emph{A reference to Theorems \textup{1} and \textup{2}.}

\end{document}
```

Edit: I've found that if I replace the `\crefdefaultlabelformat` line above with

```
\makeatletter
\crefdefaultlabelformat{\leavevmode\sw@slant#2{\upshape#1}#3}
\makeatother
```

as done in the `upref` package (see the top of page 2 of the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/amscls/doc/upref.pdf)), I seem to automatically get the italic correction in both places. But I don't know how safe this is.

Comment: Apparently the `\cref` - range capabilities are disregarding the format, at least used this way

Comment: The `\leavevmode` instruction in your modified solution would seem to be quite unnecessary. I learned something new, though: the macro `\sw@slant`, which is defined in the LaTeX kernel.

Comment: I was just copying what they did in the `upref` package; they say that `\sw@slant` gives you an error if it comes at the start of a paragraph and at some other locations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `\cref` has only two references in it's list (as in the examples here), the `\crefpairconjunction` macro should be used, here with explicit italic correction, i.e. `\/`: (see page 13 of current `cleveref.pdf` manual)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage[capitalise,nameinlink]{cleveref}

\crefdefaultlabelformat{#2\textup{#1}#3}
\newcommand{\crefpairconjunction}{ and\/ }

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}\label{thm1}
A theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}\label{thm2}
A theorem.
\end{theorem}

\emph{A reference to \cref{thm1,thm2}.}

\emph{A reference to Theorems \textup{1} and \textup{2}.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could this somehow be fixed directly in the `\crefdefaultlabelformat` command? I'm guessing that, in general, there could be other commands I'd have to change besides `\crefpairconjunction`.

Comment: @MSC: I don't know, I've to dig into `cleveref` then